# articles's title list generated by drupal views module don't have title tip

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

i used  views module genereate an articles title list, when i put the mouse hover on the article's title .three isn't a tip of the node title. the html code is  this

```
 <div class="views-field-title">
 <span class="field-content">
  <a href="/resell.html">Resell</a>
  </span>
  </div>
```

there is no title= "", label in the

```
    <a>
```

label,my views setting is add the title field and checked the l"ink this field to the node." am i right? how to make the node title tip show when i put the mouse hover on the article's title.

the drupal version is 6, views module version is 6.x-2.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "link this field to the node" you could use "output this field as a link" and set alt text to nid. To do this:

1. Add another field of nid
2. Drag field to top of list and set to exclude display
3. Set "output this field as a link" and then Link path to "node/[nid]"
4. Then set alt text to be [title]

Alternatively if the title attribute is really required you could manually add it to the template file. To see which template to edit click Theme: Information in the Basic Settings page. Copy the tpl name and code to your active themes directory and then add the title attribute.

Comment: it will do, assuming your using pathauto drupal will take care of the url aliasing for you.